# Node JS and SASS incompatibility issues in Ionic 3 project

Tags: node.js, typescript, ionic-framework, npm, sass

I'm trying to rebuild a Ionic 3.9.2 project that was coded in another machine, and I've built a new Ionic project and transferred the "foreign" project files to it. But I was getting an error referring to SASS settings when I ran `ionic serve -l` in the terminal to visualize the project, as showed in the picture:

[image]

To fix it, I uninstalled Node JS 6.11.1 64bit and installed the 32bit version. But now I'm getting new errors on terminal when trying to build the project:

First I got:

> Error: Missing binding C:\crepe\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-ia32-48\binding.node
>   Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Windows 32-bit with Node.js 6.x
>   Found bindings for the following environments:
>     - Windows 64-bit with Node.js 6.x
>   This usually happens because your environment has changed since running `npm install`.
>   Run `npm rebuild node-sass --force` to build the binding for your current environment.

So I ran the command indicated: `npm rebuild node-sass --force`

But now I'm getting a whole bunch of new errors:

> node-sass@4.5.3 install C:\crepe\node_modules\node-sass
>   node scripts/install.js
>   Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.5.3/win32-ia32-48_binding.node
>   Download complete  ] - :
>   Binary saved to C:\crepe\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-ia32-48\binding.node
>   Caching binary to C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\node-sass\4.5.3\win32-ia32-48_binding.node
>
> node-sass@4.5.3 postinstall C:\crepe\node_modules\node-sass
>   node scripts/build.js
>   Building: C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe C:\crepe\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=

```
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [ 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe',
gyp verb cli   'C:\\crepe\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library=' ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0    

gyp info using node@6.11.1 | win32 | ia32
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\crepe\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\crepe\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\crepe\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\crepe\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\crepe\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\crepe\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
gyp verb `which` failed  python2 { Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\crepe\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\crepe\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\crepe\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\crepe\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\crepe\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\crepe\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
gyp verb `which` failed   stack: 'Error: not found: python2\n    at getNotFoundError (C:\\crepe\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:13:12)\n    at F (C:\\crepe\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:68:19)\n    at E (C:\\crepe\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:80:29)\n    at C:\\crepe\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:89:16\n    at C:\\crepe\\node_modules\\isexe\\index.js:42:5\n    at C:\\crepe\\node_modules\\isexe\\windows.js:36:5\n    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)',
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT' }
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\crepe\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\crepe\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\crepe\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\crepe\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\crepe\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\crepe\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
gyp verb `which` failed  python { Error: not found: python
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\crepe\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\crepe\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\crepe\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\crepe\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\crepe\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\crepe\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)


gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\crepe\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\crepe\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\crepe\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\crepe\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\crepe\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\crepe\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
gyp verb `which` failed   stack: 'Error: not found: python2\n    at getNotFoundError (C:\\crepe\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:13:12)\n    at F (C:\\crepe\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:68:19)\n    at E (C:\\crepe\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:80:29)\n    at C:\\crepe\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:89:16\n    at C:\\crepe\\node_modules\\isexe\\index.js:42:5\n    at C:\\crepe\\node_modules\\isexe\\windows.js:36:5\n    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)',
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT' }
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\crepe\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\crepe\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\crepe\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\crepe\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\crepe\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\crepe\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
gyp verb `which` failed  python { Error: not found: python
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\crepe\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\crepe\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\crepe\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\crepe\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\crepe\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\crepe\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
gyp verb `which` failed   stack: 'Error: not found: python\n    at getNotFoundError (C:\\crepe\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:13:12)\n    at F (C:\\crepe\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:68:19)\n    at E (C:\\crepe\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:80:29)\n    at C:\\crepe\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:89:16\n    at C:\\crepe\\node_modules\\isexe\\index.js:42:5\n    at C:\\crepe\\node_modules\\isexe\\windows.js:36:5\n    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)',
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT' }
gyp verb could not find "python". checking python launcher
gyp verb could not find "python". guessing location
gyp verb ensuring that file exists: C:\Python27\python.exe
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at Object.failNoPython (C:\crepe\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:484:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\crepe\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:509:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\crepe\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:282:31
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\crepe\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd C:\crepe\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v6.11.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1
node-sass@4.5.3 C:\crepe\node_modules\node-sass
```

I'm using Ionic 3.9.2, Angular 5.0.0 and Node JS 6.11.1 32bits. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/installation/environment#node-npm), you should install [Node.js LTS](https://nodejs.org/en/)(**v10.15.3**, currently) instead of *v6.11.1*. And keep the `npm` up-to-date by

```
$ npm i -g npm
```

After updating `Node.js`, reinstall `node_modules` on the local. You'd better remove *ex*-`node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` file.

Hope it would help.

Comment: Indeed I rebuilt the `node_modules` and it worked. Thank you!